# Images preview before uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have here my upload script and it has a function that the user can preview selected images before uploading but my problem is that every time I'll upload all images available for preview it is always the last file chosen.

Heres my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function readURL(input){
            if(input.files[0]){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e){
                    $(".form-holder").append("<img class='prev' />")
                    $(".prev").attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        $("#btn_up").change(function(){

            readURL(this);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: are you uploading multiple images???

Answer (score 3):

Try This Code

**HTML**

```
<input id="imgInput" type="file"  name="file[]" multiple style="display:none;"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="$('#imgInput').click();" value="Choose File" />
         <output id="result" ></output>

    <div style="margin-top:150px;" id="uploadedcontent"></div>
```

**JS**

```
        var ftype = new Array();

        $("#imgInput").change(function () {
            readURL(this);

        });
        function readURL(input) {
            var files = input.files;
            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            var count = 0;
             var count1 = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                var picReader = new FileReader();
                var divid = 'div_' + i;
                var spanid = 'span_' + i;
                picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                    var picFile = event.target;
                    var picnames = files[count].name;
                    var mimetypes = picFile.result.split(',');
                    var mimetype1 = mimetypes[0];
                    var mimetype = mimetype1.split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
                    count++;

                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.setAttribute('id', 'div_' + count);
                    div.setAttribute('class', 'divclass');
                    if (mimetype.match('image')) {
                        div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                            "title='" + picnames + "' width='96' height='80' alt='Item Image' style='position:relative;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;' data-valu='" + mimetype + "'/><span class='boxclose' style='cursor:pointer' id='span_" + count + "'>x</span>";

                    }

                    output.insertBefore(div, null);

                });

                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }


$('body').on('click','.boxclose','',function(e){
       var spanid = $(this).attr('id');
            var splitval = spanid.split('_');
            $('#div_' + splitval[1]).remove();
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/77hLM/1/)**

Comment: woah.i was about to use dropzone.js then i checked your code and its amazing. hehe now i will have to rewrite your code for my needs. thanks sir!

Comment: how can i give you a plus rep? sorry my first time here in stack haha

Comment: sir one more thing.haha so i wanted those preview images be view horizontally. will float left be enough? and ill set the x-axis of the div scroll. just like what facebook is doing when uploading images then you get to preview them from left to right.